# What's a good media player for the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: media-player, raspberry-pi

I'm looking for a good media player that can play MP3, WMA, FLAC, and OGG audio files, as well as MP4, WMV, MKV, and VOB files with fairly good quality (320 Kbps audio and 1080p60) on my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian.

Prospective players should support the capability to create playlists and shuffle/repeat files from such playlists. In other words, it should be able to do the same things that an iPod is capable of doing.

The player should be able to output the audio and video over the HDMI port as well as the 3.5mm jack and composite video output respectively.

Comment: My first software recommendation question...tried very hard to get over my qualms against posting a recommendation question on a Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the commandline utility [`mplayer`](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html).

---

If you prefer a GUI, you should try the mpv (a fork of mplayer) frontend [Baka MPlayer](http://bakamplayer.u8sand.net/index.php).